# Manually Serve GZip Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Want to control this myself as IIS 7 is not picking up static javascript files and treating them as dynamic, which i assume will mean each time it is requested iis will use cpu to compress etc.

I can gzip my javascript with 7-Zip, how do I then serve this through my ASP.NET page?

Comment: That's different.  A lot different.
Have you tried using bundling / minification in your Web App?

Comment: i use google closure complier to minify the javascript, but also want to gzip file as this saves another 50%